# How come reading from a plist fails in my iOS application?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to create an `NSMutableDictionary` containing a list of animals in my iOS app with this function.

```
// puts animals into dictionary
- (void) putAnimalsFromPlistToDictionary
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];    
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"myAnimals" ofType:@"plist"];    
    myAnimalDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    // I set a breakpoint here in XCode.
}
```

I dragged myAnimals.plist (which looks like the below) into my supporting files folder for my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>elephant</string>
    <string>monkey</string>
    <string>cat</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

However, when I reach the breakpoint (as listed in my comment), I see that myAnimalDictionary is nil. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you have an array in your `.plist` but you're trying to instantiate a mutable dictionary instance.

Comment: Thank you. Oh dear, that plist comes from the client. I can't change it. What can I make out of it then if I can't make a dictionary? Can I make a set?

Comment: Then why do you want a dictionary of the values? The data are listed as an array.

Comment: I don't need a dictionary. I just need to somehow load a list of animals into any collection such as a set or an array. I think you're right actually - a dictionary implies key-value pairs, and I don't think I need that.

Comment: Then try `NSArray *animalArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];`